# Android ProviderInstaller and custom caches

Tags: java, android, security, httpsurlconnection

**TL;DR - The classes I need to use to allow my server to remain secure prevent my client remaining secure - I can't find a happy balance.**

I am using `HttpsUrlConnection` on android devices which are not readily accessible to humans. They run for long periods of time without being rebooted - long enough that sometimes they need to adapt slightly to a changing server. In this scenario, a security flaw shows up in the wild and the server is reconfigured to reject the vulnerable protocol.

As far as I can make out, the android device is caching the connections in some way that means once it has decided on a protocol for a server it sticks with it, even if the server starts rejecting connections. I would like it to go through the handshake again, get a new protocol, and keep working.

I *think* I can see how to do that using a custom socket factory.

However, I am also aware of security flaws showing up in the `SSL` implementation on the device.  I can fix these using `ProviderInstaller`, which updates whatever it is that needs updating using the google play store.  Ignoring for now the dialog I have to deal with when I do that, I also hit on this little warning:

> Caution: Updating a device's security Provider does not update android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory. Rather than using this class, we encourage app developers to use high-level methods for interacting with cryptography. Most apps can use APIs like HttpsURLConnection, HttpClient, and AndroidHttpClient without needing to set a custom TrustManager or create an SSLCertificateSocketFactory.

I might be misreading this, but I get the feeling that the only way I can deal with a server changing protocols to protect itself from a vulnerability is to use things which make the client unsafe instead?

Can anyone confirm, clarify or offer suggestions?

Comment: Where do you have the information about this "stick with a protocol" behavior? I never heard of such a behavior.

Comment: From observation - if I disable TLS1 and enabled SSLv3 on my server, then loop doing https connections, then I reconfigure the server to accept TLS1 but reject SSLv3, the connections start failing with protocol errors until I restart the app.

Comment: I assume this is because of a cache somewhere.